# How to define static class type for a variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an Angular2 component ***similar*** to the below code:

```
export ABC_Component class{
  ...
  private xyzObj:any;
  ...
  constructor(){
   this.xyzObj= new ABC_Component.XYZ_Class();
  }
  ...
  private static XYZ_Class = class{
   ...
  }
  ...
}
```

As you can see `xyzObj` is of type `any`. (Not issues in overall working of the code)

Is there a way do properly define its type since if I try to define it like the following: `private xyzObj:ABC_Component.XYZ_Class;` the TypeScript Linter shows `Cannot find namespace for ABC_Component`

New to both Angular2 and TypeScript. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understand what you're trying to achieve with just. It's looks weird to me that you're trying to define class inside static class property.

In any case, you didn't write this class correctly:

```
export class ABC_Component {
  private xyzObj:any;

  constructor(){
   this.xyzObj = new ABC_Component.XYZ_Class();
  }

  private static XYZ_Class = class {
  }
}
```

here is another approach, if you just want to create a class that doesn't export to others, and only using it here:

```
export class ABC_Component {
  private xyzObj: XYZ_Class;

  constructor(){
   this.xyzObj = new XYZ_Class();
  }
}

class XYZ_Class {

}
```

Comment: Forgot `this`. Wanted to know if it is possible to define the type of `xyzObj` other than `any`. Purpose was to define a class such that it is not visible outside to other classes.

Comment: so here is another approach:

`
export class ABC_Component {
  private xyzObj: XYZ_Class;
  
  constructor(){
   this.xyzObj = new XYZ_Class();
  }
}

class XYZ_Class {
 
}
`

in this example you have a class that aren't exported to others

Comment: Would I be able to use properties defined inside `XYZ_Class` with this method inside the template of the component using the `xyzObj`? Just want to confirm whether they are functionally any different.